# Spring MVC - Múltiplos Construtores

Tags: java, spring-mvc, construtor

Estou com um problema onde um Framework que estou utilizando necessita de um construtor padrão, esta chamando minha classe Service:

```
@Service
public class FuncionarioService {

private FuncionarioDAO dao;


    public FuncionarioService(){        
    }   

    @Autowired
    public FuncionarioService(FuncionarioDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
```

Ao chamar o método abaixo, a variável "dao" esta vindo "null". Ao utilizar um outro caminho que não utiliza o Framework, esta tudo normal, a variável vem diferente de "null".

```
public List<Funcionario> obterFuncionarios(Hierarquia hierarquia){
        List<Funcionario> listaFuncionarios = new ArrayList<Funcionario>();
        listaFuncionarios = dao.obterFuncionarios(hierarquia);
        return listaFuncionarios;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando fazer a instância de um objeto de serviço Spring, experimente utilizar o @Autowired para fazer a injeção deste objeto e verifique se funciona.

Quando você utiliza um @Service, você está criando um serviço com inversão de controle, podendo ser injetado. No momento que você tenta adicionar ou instanciar um objeto, podem ocorrer problemas pois você teoricamente quebra a cadeia de inversão de controle.

Comment: Thiago, já tentei adicionar o @Autowired ao construtor padrão, porem ele necessita de pelo menos 1 parametro, se não da erro.

Comment: Opa, desculpa, você não precisa adicionar ele como atributo do construtor. Tente utilizar assim:

"@Autowired"
private Dao dao;

E pode usar o objeto dao livremente, desde que ele seja um "@Service" também.

Comment: No meu DAO eu utilizo a notação @Repository =\

Comment: Perfeito, isso mesmo. Funciona do mesmo jeito, você deve estar usando Spring Data.

Comment: Não funcionou, ainda esta como Null.

Comment: Você não está injetando ele no construtor certo? Está pegando o "dao" instanciado e utilizando ele diretamente, correto?

Comment: No modo que estou utilizando, estou injetando ele no construtor. Porem para uma nova situação, ele não esta reconhecendo.

@Autowired
 public FuncionarioService(FuncionarioDAO dao) {
  this.dao = dao;
 }

Comment: Abandona essa injeção no construtor, se você já está fazendo a injeção dele na sua classe você já tem ele disponível para uso, use como coloquei anteriormente 

@Autowired
private Dao dao;

E use ele normalmente.

Comment: Não funcionou mano, continua indo como null.

@Autowired
 private FuncionarioDAO dao;

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83813/discussion-between-thiago-vulcao-and-kennedy-anderson).

Comment: Se sua classe está correta como @repositoy deveria funcionar. Você pode atualizar o post com as classes para que eu possa entender como está o DAO?